# Jquery not working in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, tabs

I'm using *Tab option* in my  `C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`, using with following Jquery,

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
      var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
      active = links.first().addClass('active');
      content = $(active.attr('href'));
      links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
      });
      $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
        active.removeClass('active');
        content.hide();
        active = $(this);
        content = $($(this).attr('href'));
        active.addClass('active');
        content.show();
        return false;
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

If I give this, **Add to Cart** is not working. Giving following error in *Console* from *prototype.js*,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent'

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'
```

If I remove, `<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` then **Add to Cart** working fine. But 'Tab option' not working.

How I can Implement Both?

Comment: check for the conflict issue using firebug .

Comment: "  $($(this).attr('href'))"... Is that really a selector that matches anything?

Comment: always use jQuery.noConflict() for your custom jquery code and lib.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>jQuery.noConflict()</script>
        <script>
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
              var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
              active = links.first().addClass('active');
              content = $(active.attr('href'));
              links.not(':first').each(function () {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
              });
              $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
                active.removeClass('active');
                content.hide();
                active = $(this);
                content = $($(this).attr('href'));
                active.addClass('active');
                content.show();
                return false;
              });
            });
          });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this.......

```
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery.noConflict();
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('ul.tabs').each(function(){
          var active, content, links = $j(this).find('a');
          active = links.first().addClass('active');
          content = $j(active.attr('href'));
          links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $j($j(this).attr('href')).hide();
          });
          $j(this).find('a').click(function(e){
        active.removeClass('active');
        content.hide();
        active = $j(this);
        content = $j($j(this).attr('href'));
        active.addClass('active');
        content.show();
        return false;
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding jQuery library into view.phtml and other prototype library are already loaded on page. That's why it raising error. Add this jQuery library from layout `catalog.xml`.

Add External JS Method:

```
<action method="setText">
<text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]></text>
</action>
```

OR

Download library and keep into `js/` directory and add it from there.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery.min.js</script></action>
```

Hope will help!

Comment: thanks dude. I didn't try more complicated. So just used simple that ans.

Comment: It's your choice, I have shared only best way to add custom js library into magento. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the jquery.min.js file in Head.phtml , also add jQuery.noConflict() jut below the  jquery.min.js inseated of calling js on individual page.

then, there will not be any js conflicting issue  :)